# TensorFlow attention_decoder with RNNCell (state_is_tuple=True)

Tags: tensorflow

I want to build a seq2seq model with an attention_decoder, and to use MultiRNNCell with LSTMCell as the encoder. Because the TensorFlow code suggests that "This default behaviour (state_is_tuple=False) will soon be deprecated.", I set the state_is_tuple=True for the encoder.

The problem is that, when I pass the state of encoder to attention_decoder, it reports an error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'LSTMStateTuple' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

This problem seems to be related to the attention() function in seq2seq.py and the _linear() function in rnn_cell.py, in which the code calls the 'get_shape()' function of the 'LSTMStateTuple' object from the initial_state generated by the encoder.

Although the error disappears when I set state_is_tuple=False for the encoder, the program gives the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:<tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell.LSTMCell object at 0x11763dc50>: Using a concatenated state is slower and will soon be deprecated.  Use state_is_tuple=True.
```

I would really appreciate if someone can give any instruction about building seq2seq with RNNCell (state_is_tuple=True).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also, the lstm states need to be concatenated or else `_linear` will complain. The shape of `LSTMStateTuple` depends on the kind of cell you're using. With a LSTM cell, you can concatenate the states like this:

```
 query = tf.concat(1,[state[0], state[1]])
```

If you're using a `MultiRNNCell`, concatenate the states for each layer first:

```
 concat_layers = [tf.concat(1,[c,h]) for c,h in state]
 query = tf.concat(1, concat_layers)
```